# RegEx Show Text From (1st Matching Char) to (2nd Matching Char)

Tags: regex, vb.net

I want to get my application to show one certain part of an html code of a website. The part I'd like to have starts with `<span> <PRE>` and ends with `</PRE></span>`. I considered using RegEx and a StringBuilder to do that.

```
    Dim Fetcher As New StringBuilder
    Fetcher.AppendLine(Regex.Match((New Net.WebClient).DownloadString("https://pilotweb.nas.faa.gov/PilotWeb/notamRetrievalByICAOAction.do?method=displayByICAOs&reportType=RAW&formatType=DOMESTIC&retrieveLocId=" & ICAOCode.Text & "&actionType=notamRetrievalByICAOs"), "<span> <PRE>)").Value)
    OutputBox.Text = Fetcher.ToString
```

It should show a long text but instead only shows `<span> <PRE>`

Comment: The first part was messed up by SO. It should be: The part I'd like to have starts with "<span> <PRE>" and ends with "</PRE></span>".

Comment: You're only telling to look for `<span> <PRE>` so that's what you get. You might want to have a look at the [Regex Language Quick Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/regular-expression-language-quick-reference).